# Groovy GString, multiple line regex - how to count number of lines?

Tags: regex, groovy

I just want to add something at the beginning of each line and at the end of each line:

```
def mystring="""
hello
world
"""
matcher = (mystring =~ /(?ms)^/);
excerpt = matcher.replaceAll("put '");
matcher = (excerpt  =~ /(?ms)$/);
excerpt2 = matcher.replaceAll(" ';");
println excerpt2
```

I expected to have

```
  put 'hello';
  put 'world';
```

However, I got

```
put ' ';
put 'hello ';
put 'world ';
 ';
```

which means that there is a "^" after """ even there is not a real line.  Can we say that by using (?m), we have created 3 lines?

Thanks.

Comment: May be you just need replace `\n` with `'\n'`, and strip `'` after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want I think:

```
def mystring="""
hello
world
"""

matcher = mystring =~ /(?ms)^(.*?)$/
excerpt = matcher.collect{ "put '${it[0]}';" }.join( '\n' )
println excerpt
```

At least for me, that prints out

```
put '';
put 'hello';
put 'world';
```

Comment: changing `(.*?)` to `([^\n]+)` will skip blank lines btw.

Comment: Could you explain what this regex is doing? `(?ms)^(.*?)$`